# how to print stdclass object name to data

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, stdclass, ezsql

i used ezsql mysqli and my mysql scheme:

```
    id---settingname------settingcode
---------------------------------
0    doctype          <!DOCTYPE html>
1    html_lang        en
2    charset          utf8
```

and my php code

```
<?php echo $doctype; ?>
<html lang="<?php echo $html_lang; ?>">
<meta charset="<?php echo $charset; ?>">
```

how can i fetch stdclass object like this with ezsql mysqli;

```
echo $settings['doctype'];
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029120/how-to-access-stdclass-variables-stdclass-objectmaxid-64?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access stdClass variables stdClass Object(\[max(id)\])=>64)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029120/how-to-access-stdclass-variables-stdclass-objectmaxid-64)

Comment: You show an array so `$settings = get_results($query, ARRAY_A);` or use `OBJECT`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i found the answer, you can change index with array_column() like this;

```
$settings = array_column($dbresult,'settingcode','settinguniquename');
```

and you can print this variable like this;

```
echo $settings['doctype']; echo $settings['charset']; echo $settings['anysettingname'];
```